# How to parse out substring?

Tags: bash

I want to get a substring between two other substrings.

Here is the string:

```
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="FileabcName123One/">FileabcName123One/</a></td><td align="right">08-Mar-2019 19:53  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

I want to parse out the substring which is between the substrings 'href="' and '/">':

```
FileabcName123One
```

Comment: If you are OK with external tools: https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/ has some utilities to parse HTML.

Comment: No, won't be able to use external tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input string is stored in the `INPUT` environment variable you can use `#` and `%` into [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to remove prefixes and suffixes from the value:

```
$ INPUT='<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"></td><td><a href="FileabcName123One/">FileabcName123One/</a></td><td align="right">08-Mar-2019 19:53  </td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>'

$ TEMP=${INPUT#*href=\"}
$ OUTPUT=${TEMP%%/\"*}

$ echo $OUTPUT
FileabcName123One
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's_.*href="\(.*\)/">.*'_\\1_ <INPUTFILE
```